# Don't Trigger DataTrigger on Sort

Tags: wpf

I have a datagrid with a datatrigger that triggers a row animation when a value in the viewmodel changes. This works, but it is also triggered when the row comes into the viewport. So when I sort (via clicking the column header), filter or scroll, the row animation happens.

How can I make it so the animation is only triggered when the value in the viewmodel changes?

```
<DataGrid IsReadOnly="True" x:Name="Cards">
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Obtained}" Value="True">
                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" From="#C8E6C9" Duration="0:0:3"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding Obtained}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
        <!-- etc... -->
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

I'm not sure if this matters, but the grid is bound to a ReactiveUI `IReactiveDerivedList` with a `ReactiveList` as the source.

Comment: Have you tried `SuppressChangeNotifications`? Take a look at [ReactiveUI goodies](https://janhannemann.wordpress.com/2016/10/06/reactiveui-goodies-reactivelist/)

Comment: Hmm, maybe I'm misunderstanding what `SuppressChangeNotifications` does, but I don't have any issues with my viewmodel updating my view. My issue crops up when, for example, I click on a header in the grid to sort the grid.

Comment: Do you mean ReactiveUI handles the sorting? (I haven't used it myself). If the answer is yes, then maybe you should override that behaviour, handle the sorting in your code and not raise any events

Comment: It doesn't. It just uses the out-of-the-box sorting that a `DataGrid` provides.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure this is not the optimal solution, but hopefully it will point you to the right direction. I added a boolean property to the class, I set it to **True** when **Obtained** is set to **True** and reset it to **False** in its **get** method.

**XAML**

```
    <DataGrid x:Name="Cards">
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=ObtainedChangedToTrue}" Value="True">
                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" From="#C8E6C9" Duration="0:0:3"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding Obtained}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
        <!-- etc... -->
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

**Code Behind**

```
private bool _obtained;
public bool Obtained
{
    get
    {
        return _obtained;
    }
    set
    {
        if(SetField(ref _obtained, value))
        {
            ObtainedChangedToTrue = true;
        }
        else
        {
            ObtainedChangedToTrue = false;
        }
    }
}

private bool _obtainedChangedToTrue;
public bool ObtainedChangedToTrue
{
    get
    {
        bool result = _obtainedChangedToTrue;
        _obtainedChangedToTrue = false;
        return result;
    }
    set
    {
        SetField(ref _obtainedChangedToTrue, value);
    }
}
```